# mql4: Get data from site

Tags: trading, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading, mql4, forex

How I can get "**`Maintenance`**" value from site

[image]

using a **`MQL4`** script ?

As I understand, I must set an internet connection, get data from site, parse it and get data.

Is there a way how I can do it?

I'll be grateful for any example.

Comment: Be more specific. Plus, the thumbnail is so tiny you can't quite read anything.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 I changed main post

Comment: Alright, what do you mean by *getting* the value? Obviously you already *got* it. Do you mean fetching and storing that value (perodically?) via some program?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 yes, i mean fetching and storing

Comment: There are too many possible answers then. Use your favourite search engine; you'll find plenty ways to do this. E.g. search for curl or wget. Then come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

### Fact #1: MQL4 syntax restricts calling external sub-process:

This means ( if not using a DLL-workaround ) the whole task would require to re-invent a wheel and build the HTML-parser inside MQL4. Doable but a waste of anyone's resources.

### Fact #2: There are better ways to choose from:

Once going to use a DLL-imported functionalities, one may either just bypass the MQL4 code-execution restrictions and call Windows-API services to fork sub-process and make things move forwards, however Windows-API, in my opinion, is rather a feature rich interfacing framework, but for a pretty low-level access to elementary services, so you finally can find yourself re-inventing wheel again, well, now "outside" from the MQL4 sandbox restrictions.

If you do not restrict our imagination, your project may benefit from rapid-prototyping in Python and setup a peer-to-peer distributed messaging/control in a heterogeneous Python / MQL4 environment.

Besides other benefits, Python strengths in smart and powerful ( not only ) web-content processing is fabulous, so this distributed approach will open your MQL4 projects into strategically new, unseen dimensions.

---

Python smart-scraping ( not a dumb-force one ):

```
def askAtPublisherWebURL( aControlDICT,
                          aURL             = "https://globalde?.?.?.?y?.com/en/products/.../...-DLON?Class_type=class_symbol=???&Class_exchange=???&ps=999&md=03-2014",
                          anOPT            = "ESX",
                          aMaturityDATE    = "03-2014",
                          anEmailRECIPIENT = "Me.Robot-GWY-2013-PoC@gmail.com",
                          aFileNAME        = "ESX_2014-03_anObservedStateTIMESTAMP[]"
                          ):
    import      time, urllib, re, winsound, urllib2             # late, dirty import

    try:
        aReturnFLAG     = True
        anOutputSTRING  = "|TRYING: " + aURL                    # a crash-proof proxy-value for a case IOError <EXC> would appear
      # --------------------------------------------------------# urllib2 MODE        
        anInputHANDLER  = urllib2.urlopen( aURL, None, 120 )    # urllib2 MODE with a 120 [sec] timeout before urllib2.URLError ... still gets stuck during peak-hours ( on aMaturityDATE )
        aListOfLINEs    = anInputHANDLER.readlines()
        anInputHANDLER.close()
      # --------------------------------------------------------# urllib2 MODE
    except urllib2.URLError as anExcREASON:
        aReturnFLAG     = False
                                                                # no RET here // JMP .FINALLY: to log IOError....

    except exceptions.IOError as ( ErrNO, ErrSTR ):             # an IOError <EXC> hase appeared, handle with care before JMP .FINALLY:
        aReturnFLAG     = False

    else:                                                       # no IOError or any other <EXC>, process the <content> .. JMP .FINALLY:
        # ------------------------------------------------------# HTML-processor
        # smart html-processing goes here
        # ...
        # ------------------------------------------------------# HTML-processor
    finally:                                                    # in any case do all this TIDY-UP-BEFORE-EXIT
        # fileIO + pre-exit ops
        # sendMsg4MQL() --> SIG MT4

    return aReturnFLAG # MISRA-motivated single point of RET
```

---

<sub>For hawkish Pythoneers, the post intentionally uses non-PEP-8 source code formatting as it is authors experience that during a learning phase, code read-ability improves the focus on task solution and helps getting used to the underlying concepts rather than to spend efforts on formally adhering typography. Hope the principle of providing help is respected and the non-PEP-8 styling format is forgiven in the name of the ease of reading.</sub>

Comment: I using Groovy in my work. I can get page from url and then parse it, but then I must paste getting values into mql4 script, compilate it for using in mt4 terminal

Comment: Prijatno, lsv, Groovy has also support available for **ZeroMQ** so your way to powerfull worlds of fully distributed heterogenous processing are free & open. Enjoy the day ( btw, a nice poker-face :o) )

Comment: Besides Austen Conrad's lovely DLL-wrapper, there are some efforts on porting also a "younger-sister" of `ZeroMQ`, a **`nanomsg`** framework tools for **`MQL4`**, but time is so fast to make all things happen now.